# std::map with values of different function-types

Tags: c++, c++20, stdmap, variant, std-variant

I want to use a `std::map` with certain types of functions (certain, specific parameter types) as possible values. However, the following (minimal) example does not compile.

Why is that and how can I allow `FunctionType<bool>` and `FunctionType<int>` as possible values for the Map?

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <variant>


template <typename T>
using FunctionType = std::function<T(T)>;


int main()
{
  auto myMap = std::map<std::string, std::variant<FunctionType<bool>, FunctionType<int>>>
    {
     {"foo", [](bool x){return x;}},
     {"bar", [](int x){return x;}},
    };

  return 0;
}
```

Error message:

```sh
$ g++ --std=c++2a -o /tmp/variant-test /tmp/variant-test.cpp && /tmp/variant-test

variant-test.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
variant-test.cpp:18:5: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > >::map(<brace-enclosed initializer list>)’
   18 |     };
      |     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/map:61,
                 from variant-test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:290:2: note: candidate: ‘template<class _InputIterator> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::map(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const _Compare&, const allocator_type&) [with _InputIterator = _InputIterator; _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> >; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > > >]’
  290 |  map(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
      |  ^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:290:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
variant-test.cpp:18:5: note:   candidate expects 4 arguments, 2 provided
   18 |     };
      |     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/map:61,
                 from variant-test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:273:2: note: candidate: ‘template<class _InputIterator> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::map(_InputIterator, _InputIterator) [with _InputIterator = _InputIterator; _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> >; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > > >]’
  273 |  map(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last)
      |  ^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:273:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
variant-test.cpp:18:5: note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘_InputIterator’
   18 |     };
      |     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/map:61,
                 from variant-test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:256:2: note: candidate: ‘template<class _InputIterator> std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::map(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const allocator_type&) [with _InputIterator = _InputIterator; _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> >; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > > >]’
  256 |  map(_InputIterator __first, _InputIterator __last,
      |  ^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:256:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
variant-test.cpp:18:5: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 2 provided
   18 |     };
      |     ^
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/map:61,
                 from variant-test.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:250:7: note: candidate: ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::map(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >, const allocator_type&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> >; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > > >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > > >]’
  250 |       map(initializer_list<value_type> __l, const allocator_type& __a)
      |       ^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:250:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::initializer_list<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > > >’
  250 |       map(initializer_list<value_type> __l, const allocator_type& __a)
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:244:7: note: candidate: ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::map(std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&&, const allocator_type&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> >; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > > >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > > >]’
  244 |       map(map&& __m, const allocator_type& __a)
      |       ^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:244:17: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > >&&’
  244 |       map(map&& __m, const allocator_type& __a)
      |           ~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:240:7: note: candidate: ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::map(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const allocator_type&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> >; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > > >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > > >]’
  240 |       map(const map& __m, const allocator_type& __a)
      |       ^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:240:22: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘const std::map<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > >&’
  240 |       map(const map& __m, const allocator_type& __a)
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:236:7: note: candidate: ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::map(const allocator_type&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> >; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > > >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > > >]’
  236 |       map(const allocator_type& __a)
      |       ^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:236:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:228:7: note: candidate: ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::map(std::initializer_list<std::pair<const _Key, _Tp> >, const _Compare&, const allocator_type&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> >; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > > >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > > >]’
  228 |       map(initializer_list<value_type> __l,
      |       ^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:228:40: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::initializer_list<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > > >’
  228 |       map(initializer_list<value_type> __l,
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:215:7: note: candidate: ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::map(std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> >; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > > >]’
  215 |       map(map&&) = default;
      |       ^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:215:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:207:7: note: candidate: ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::map(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> >; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > > >]’
  207 |       map(const map&) = default;
      |       ^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:207:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:194:7: note: candidate: ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::map(const _Compare&, const allocator_type&) [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> >; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > > >; std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::allocator_type = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > > >]’
  194 |       map(const _Compare& __comp,
      |       ^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:194:27: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘const std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >&’
  194 |       map(const _Compare& __comp,
      |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:185:7: note: candidate: ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::map() [with _Key = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Tp = std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> >; _Compare = std::less<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >; _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::variant<std::function<bool(bool)>, std::function<int(int)> > > >]’
  185 |       map() = default;
      |       ^~~
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/stl_map.h:185:7: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 2 provided
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the one-user-defined-conversion rule. It's easy to see this by taking your example and replacing `FunctionType<int>` with `FunctionType<std::string>` - everything compiles.

`variant<X, Y>` is implicitly convertible from everything that converts to `X` or `Y`, *provided that* it can unambiguously determine the type to convert to. The proviso is important because `std::function` doesn't require exact matches: a `std::function<bool(bool)>` accepts everything that can be called with a `bool` and returns something that can be converted to a `bool`. Obviously `[](bool x) { return x; }` meets this requirement, but `[](int x) { return x; }` does so too. Similarly, both of these lambdas can be converted to a `std::function<int(int)>` because they can both be called with an `int` to produce something that's convertible to an `int`.

Since the lambdas are convertible to both alternatives, and there is no ordering between the two, `variant` will just refuse to convert from it. This is why replacing `FunctionType<int>` with `FunctionType<std::string>` makes it compile - only the `bool` alternative is viable in that case.

Comment: Thank you. The previously accepted answer got deleted, so  you could modify the first paragraph.

Comment: Are you aware of a function type that does require exact matches? I.e. a function type I could use to get rid of the otherwise needed explicit conversion to a template specialisation of `FunctionType`?